# Emacs freezing when asking Jedi/Auto Complete information while Interpreter is busy

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, emacs, autocomplete

I just now realize what is causing the trouble:

Whenever the interpreter is busy, my Emacs buffer containing the python script buffer gets stuck, as I suspect that Emacs is trying to get the information of a function, and display it as a pop up. My usual solution is to spam `C-g`, but that gets old quickly.

It has been bothering me for months, did anyone find a solution (such as a separate thread for the python info)? Even simply ceasing Jedi work while the interpreter is busy really would save a lot of frustration.

I am using Jedi, auto-complete, Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 (the problems occur in both), on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe disable auto-complete at all? BTW from my feeling relying on company, not jedi, the distraction from auto-complete in most cases is far over gain. Emacs comes with a lot of great tools making edits faster: abbrev, dabbrev etc. which seem much more efficient. Well, if jedi delivers really intelligent completions, it might be part of the game.

Comment: Yea, I am looking at company-mode right now! I am having trouble with the setup, but the main dislike with Jedi IS autocomplete. Also, the minibuffer does not work for me there, so I'm hoping to switch to company. Eldoc is the best. Are you running company-mode through a package manager?

Comment: Actually, the only concern is that the info pops up in the minibuffer,  without auto-complete, but disappears within a second.

Comment: Still hangs using only Jedi (even though I now got the minibuffer to show, quite in a buggy way)

Comment: And I totally agree, I just want to see what functions offer in the minibuffer, I'm not so much interested in the auto-complete.

Comment: Here python-mode.el is in use, which provides access to company - see in directory completion. No hang so far. However, as said, mostly it's off...